# Display a notification for the testcase been executed using cake script

Tags: .net, powershell, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cakebuild

I'm using the below cake script to run my `NUnit` test suite project. I am using `PowerShell` for execution. I have over 17000 `NUnit` test cases and it cases waiting for a long time over a blank screen. I like to get a notification in `PowerShell` about which test-case is been currently executed.

```
Task("Run-Unit-Tests")
.Does(() =>
{
if(IsRunningOnWindows())
{
    MSBuild(currentDirectory + "./Test/NUnit_Example.csproj", settings =>
    settings.SetConfiguration(configuration).AddFileLogger(new MSBuildFileLogger() ));
}
});
```

I am expecting something like the below,

```
"TestCase_1" is completed
"TestCase_2" is in progress
```

Forget about the combinations for each test case.Just displaying the name of the test case which currently been executed is enough.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you running tests as a MSBuild task? If you instead use the console runner you'll get more console output, example usage:

```
#tool nuget:?package=NUnit.ConsoleRunner&version=3.4.0

Task("Run-Unit-Tests")
    .IsDependentOn("Build")
    .Does(() =>
{
    NUnit3("./src/**/bin/" + configuration + "/*.Tests.dll",
        new NUnit3Settings {
            NoResults = true
        });
});
```

You can find a complete example [here](https://github.com/cake-build/example/blob/master/build.cake).